# How to set the initial value to ng-model when using ui-date in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

My model is based off of a JSON object and the date comes in as 2012-12-13T00:00:00-07:00

I want to use the date picker ui-date.

I have the following code that works.

```
<input ng-model="course.startDate" value="{{item.startDate | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy'}}" ui-date ng-required="true">
```

However,I don't think I should be using the `value="{{item.startDate | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy'}}"` part but without it the input doesn't load with the value from the model.

The model is bound and functions correctly when I chose a date, it just shows up empty when the page loads.

What is the correct way to initialize this input?

Answer (score 3):

Using `ui-date` and `ng-model` should be enough:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <input ng-model="date" ui-date>
</div>
```

Provided that the `MyCtrl` is defined like this:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.date= new Date();
}​
```

Here is a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MvGFF/2/

What you must know is that the `ui-date` **expects model value to be an instance of Date**, maybe you are passing a string (or other type) value?

If your model holds values that are strings and you still want to use a date-picker you need to add the `ui-date-format` directive like in this example:

```
<input ng-model="date" ui-date ui-date-format>
```

where the controller is defined like so:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.date= "2012-12-13T00:00:00-07:00";
}​
```

Here is a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d4xz2/1/

Comment: I see what's going on now.  It's the date format comming from the restful service.

I'm getting 2012-12-13T00:00:00-07:00 but ui-date expects 2012-10-30T00:00:00.001Z.

If I'm unable to get the service changed, is there an easy way to get ui-date to accept the format I'm receiving?

Comment: Adding ui-date-format now sets the initial value to the date in my model like I want, so we're close.  However, if I chose a date from the date picker the $scope.date is unset.  (same in the new jsfiddle)

Comment: You should be able to use that format to create a new date object. Then pass the object to UI Date.

Answer (score -1):

This works fine :

```
<input type="text" ng-model="nota.fechaPub" value="{{nota.fechaPub}}" ui-date ui-date-format>
```

where $scope.nota.fechaPub value is "2013-01-14T23:00:00.000Z"

The value that appears in the text box is "01/15/2013"