# How to set current weekend date as default date in jQuery calendar or Angular Js calendar.. Week ends on Sunday

Tags: jquery, angularjs, weekend

I need a calendar picker with default date is selected to be a weekend date(Sunday). Need  it in jQuery or Angular JS

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following function when initializing the value of the datepicker

```
function getSunday(d)
{
    return new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate() – d.getDay() + 7);
}
```

source: https://dukelupus.wordpress.com/2010/02/02/javascript-dates-get-monday-get-sunday-get-last-day-of-a-month/

resources:

[Set initial value in datepicker with jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9921944/set-initial-value-in-datepicker-with-jquery)

[How to set the initial value to ng-model when using ui-date in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13654420/how-to-set-the-initial-value-to-ng-model-when-using-ui-date-in-angularjs)